# how to insert the data from csv file into sqlite db?

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, python-3.x

There is a csv file in the format.

```
x1  0  1  3  6
x2  4  9  4  5
x3  8  6  7  1
```

I want insert it into a database with three fields "x1","x2","x3" into the following data.

```
x1|x2|x3
0|4|8
1|9|6
3|10|7
6|5|1
```

I think that  i have to transform the data when i read the csv file.

```
import sqlite3
db="test.sqlite"
con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()
dat=open("data","r")
for id,line in enumerate(dat.readlines()):
    ?

con.executemany('insert into test values(?,?,?)', value)
```

how to get the right format of value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose the data with `zip(*rows)`, remove the first line and insert with an `.executemany()` call:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

with open('data', 'r', newline='') as infh:
    rows = list(csv.reader(infh))
    columns = zip(*rows)
    next(columns, None)  # skip the first column

    with sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.executemany('insert into test values (?, ?, ?)', columns)
```

Comment: a little bug here,it should be `with open('data', 'r') as infh:` not `rb`.

Comment: No, it should be opened in binary mode; this is intentional.

Comment: Unless you are using Python 3; use `open('data', 'r', newline='')` in that case. The `csv` module handles newlines directly and if you open the file in text mode (Python 2) or with universal line ending handling (Python 3) you bypass that functionality.

Comment: i am in python3.3 ,`with open('data', 'r') as infh:` works fine for me,`with open('data', 'rb')` can't.

Comment: Ah, then use `newline=''`. You didn't specify a version nor did your post contain enough hints so I assumed to most common Python version (2) instead.

Comment: why i got `TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`?

Comment: I revise it into `  
    rows=[row[1:] for row in rows]
    col=zip(*rows)` ,it's ok now.

Comment: Right, Python 3 again. Adjusted. It would have helped had you included that version information earlier. :-)